# Flask app.route("/authors/add" button Could not build url for endpoint '/authors/add'. Did you mean 'authors' instead?

Tags: python, flask, routes

I added a button to add an author in my authors.html page but the button's
url is causing problems with this error

```
werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint '/authors/add'. Did you mean 'authors' instead?
```

authors.html

```
<a href="{{ url_for('/authors/add')}}">  <button type="button" id="addAuthorButton" class="btn-primary" name="button">Add Author</button></a>
```

routes.py

```
  @app.route("/authors")
  def authors():
  ....

  @app.route("/authors/add",methods=['GET','POST'])
  def addAuthor():
form =createAuthorForm()
return render_template('addAuthor.html',form=form)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`url_for()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#url-building) takes a function name as a parameter, not an url. Try this:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('addAuthor')}}">  …
```